# Black lines in Chrome and edge on Windows Server 2022 Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-server-2022, chrome

Black lines in Chrome on Windows Server 2022 VM

I'm seeing this strange interlacing/artifact on a 2022 and 2019 Windows Server Remote Desktop Host. This appears to afflict only Chrome and MSEdge (Firefox is unaffected) This is visible both via the console and RDP sessions. On another Server 2022 instance, this was seen to go away with a reboot, but it has lingered on the RDP box much to the chagrin of users.

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWHVk.png) via Youtube. Scrolling and video playback seem to cause this to pulsate.

I have attempted the following without success:

#### Within Chrome

- Disabled hardware acceleration  Disabled 2d canvas acceleration
- Disabled GPU Rasterization Updated Chrome to most recent version x64
  (114.0.5735.199) Completely reinstalled Chrome.

#### Within Windows

- Processed all possible Windows updates
- DISM / SFC / CHKDSK
- reboot (I'm a professional, of course)

These are all Hyper-V virtual machines, so a physical GPU cannot be blamed. I'd appreciate any insight.